# Certain user input works fine the first time, runs into exception the second time

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input, user-input

EDIT: I found the issue. At some points my code is asking for integers even though my list has floats. I changed int to float and it seems to be working now.

I apologize in advance for mistakes, english isn't my native language.

i am very new to coding (Python 3.x) and trying to code a very simple textbased game just for fun.

The way it works is that it copies a csv file into a list.

The format of the file is:
no., question, answer1, answer2, reply1, reply2, element1, element2, value_element1, value_element2, next_question1, next_question2

The 1 behind the header stands for the values and actions that happen, if you select answer 1 and same goes for answer 2.

I ask for the input by putting a while True >> try loop. My issue is that as soon as i reach the second question, my input doesn't get accepted anymore if i put in 2. 1 works perfectly fine.

I apologize if this isn't enough information. I'm gonna put a part of the code here aswell as a download link to the .py file.

Any help would be appreciated

The loop:

```
def quiz():
    global next_q
    global health
    print("\n{}".format(events[int(next_q)][1]))
    options = "\n(1) {} | (2) {}\n\n> ".format(events[int(next_q)][2], events[int(next_q)][3])
    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input(options))
            print(answer)
            print(type(answer))
            if answer == 1:
                print(events[int(next_q)][4])
                if events[int(next_q)][6] == "health":
                    pre_health = health
                    health += int(events[int(next_q)][8])
                    print("\n\n\nHP: {} >>> {}.\n".format(pre_health, health))
                next_q = events[int(next_q)][10]
                break
            elif answer == 2:
                print(events[int(next_q)][5])
                if events[int(next_q)][7] == "health":
                    pre_health = health
                    health += int(events[int(next_q)][9])
                    print("\n\n\nHP: {} >>> {}.\n".format(pre_health, health))
                next_q = events[int(next_q)][11]
                break
            elif answer == 0:
                next_q = events[int(next_q)][0]
                reset(next_q)
                print("\nAuf Wiedersehen!")
                quit()
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("\nBitte gebe 1 oder 2 ein.")
    quiz()
```

The downloadlink for the code, the csv. file and a save.txt file, which saves the progress and loads it upon starting the game: https://www.mediafire.com/file/817ud3y725zsx55/OneDrive_1_22.6.2021.zip/file

Comment: I'd say that the breaks break it

Comment: I'm not sure, but i put them there so the loop stops and the next function that gets called is quiz(), so it basically starts over. Atleast to my understanding. I've tried putting quiz() instead of break to no success.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the code you provided does not run alone (missing `events`, `reset`).

Comment: Remove the `break`s and be careful with your floating points in the CSV, they should be `2.5` and not `2,5`! And please do yourself a favor and learn how to use a debuuger, e.g. with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). That will make things a lot easier.

Comment: @OcasoProtal Thank you for your suggestion. I installed VS Code which seems to be a lot better than my interpreter. I identified the issue immediately with it. My code is asking for integers at some points even though my list has floats. I'm still new at coding but it's fun to keep learning!